# В: В какой части приложения Android нужно хранить ключи доступа к API

Tags: android, gradle, best-practice

В какой части приложения Android нужно хранить ключи доступа к API (хост, порт, логин, пароль и т.д.), которые изменяются в зависимости от типа сборки? Прочитав [Configure build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants), я подумал, что это стоит делать в конфигурации (build.gradle). Какие еще варианты есть? И есть ли какие-то Best Practice для решения этого вопроса?

Comment: А какая цель хранения? Например есть ли задача чтобы эти ключи нельзя было вытащить из приложения? или же чисто удобство?

Comment: Цель хранения - чтобы, например, из кода приложения можно было обращаться к переменной хоста, которая может быть разной, в зависимости от сборки. Я не знаю, можно ли ее потом вытащить, но желательно, наверное, чтобы нельзя было.

Comment: Тогда вам именно на конфигурации gradle смотреть. Другой вариант для динамического изменения https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/ Чтобы прятать ключи - надежного варианта нет, только с сервера, а тогда надо проще сделать проксию Вот еще - https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android

Comment: Но ведь если использовать Firebase Remote Config, то все равно в гит придется отдавать ключи доступа к нему? Плюс только в том, что я смогу без повторных сборок проекта менять точку доступа к API?

Answer (score 1):

Если отвлечься от истории о сохранности ключей (ну чтобы декомпиляцией невозможно было их извлечь), то можно использовать механизм `BuildConfig`:

Вот что пишет об этом мануал:

> At build time, Gradle generates the BuildConfig class so your app code can inspect information about the current build. You can also add custom fields to the BuildConfig class from your Gradle build configuration file using the buildConfigField() method and access those values in your app's runtime code. Likewise, you can add app resource values with resValue().

Правда, он реализован в виде плагина, при этом для Android это плагин уже включен из коробки.

При наличии `BuildConfig`, можно в `build.gradle` использовать такие декларации:

```
buildTypes {
    def SERVER_URL = "SERVER_URL"

debug {
     buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"http://www.myserver.com\""
}
```

и далее в Java тексте к нему обратиться так:

```
 String serverUrl=BuildConfig.SERVER_URL;
```

Comment: это `build.gradle` файл из корневого каталога проекта, или из папки модуля используется в ответе? Ещё вопрос,через `def` - возможно объявление любых переменных (**def** SERVER_URL...)?

Comment: Без разницы какой `build.gradle` использовать, но логичнее будет там где варианты сборки описываются.`def` это декларация переменной - можно конечно же любую переменную.

Comment: А если все-таки задаться вопросом сохранности ключей? То что должно измениться?